# Importing data from one workspace to another workspace

Tags: oracle-apex-5

In oracle apex export of data from table is done in .csv format and during loading the data into another workspace it shows an error `ORA-01843: not a valid month`

I tried to import the data in .xml format but it also produces an error:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing LPX-00222: error received from SAX callback function ORA-02291: integrity constraint (RETAIL_CLOUD.RCM_CUSTOMER_FK2) violated - parent key not found
```

Could someone help me to sort out this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got something wrong. A workspace is a container for your Apex applications, it doesn't contain *user data*. That's what your question suggests ("export data in a CSV format"). Data is stored in a table (which resides in a *tablespace*) and belongs to a certain user.

As of an invalid month: check whether NLS settings are equal for both source and target. For example, 20.03.2018 can't be valid if date format is set to YYYY-MM-DD. Or, if your dates were stored in a VARCHAR2 column and now should be inserted into a DATE data type column, you should beware invalid dates (such as Feb 30th or 30.42.2018 etc.).

Trying to do that via XML produces an error which doesn't have anything to do with the previous one - it says that you are trying to load *child* values into some table, but its *parent* doesn't exist yet which violated the foreign key constraint.

If I were you, I wouldn't migrate data with CSV nor XML files, but use Oracle's (Data Pump) Export & Import utilities which are designed for such things. I encourage you to investigate Data Pump, or - at least - original EXP and IMP utilities.

**[EDIT: example of a simple EXP/IMP utilities usage]**

User SCOTT has table named DEPT. I'd like to export it, and then import it to  MIKE's schema (which currently doesn't have that table):

```
SQL> connect mike/lion@orcl
Connected.
SQL> select * from tab where tname = 'DEPT';

no rows selected

SQL> $exp scott/tiger@orcl tables=dept file=my_export.dmp

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pet O×u 9 08:23:13 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Tes
Export done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set

About to export specified tables via Conventional Path ...
. . exporting table                           DEPT          4 rows exported
Export terminated successfully without warnings.
```

Export has been done. Now, import:

```
SQL> $imp mike/lion@orcl file=my_export.dmp full=y

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pet O×u 9 08:23:29 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Tes

Export file created by EXPORT:V11.02.00 via conventional path

Warning: the objects were exported by SCOTT, not by you

import done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
. importing SCOTT's objects into MIKE
. importing SCOTT's objects into MIKE
. . importing table                         "DEPT"          4 rows imported
Import terminated successfully without warnings.
```

It has also finished successfully. Finally, let's check whether MIKE now has the DEPT table and what's in there:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "MIKE"
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

As you can see, it is quite simple. Both EXP and IMP have numerous parameters you can use; once again - check the documentation.

Comment: Thank you..but will EXP and IMP utilities help to import the data for the table

Comment: Certainly. I've added an example, have a look.